# Application of the $\delta$ distribution to a function which is not a Schwartz-Function?

Tags: functions, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

I come from the field of Physics, where lecturers roughly don't care that the $\delta$-distribution is not a function. In Physics, it is just used as if it were a function, in textbooks or lecture notes people will integrate over the $\delta$-function, multiplied with some other function, and are fine.

From my own studies, I however know that the $\delta$-Distribution is a non regular Distribution, that can be defined as a linear functional over the [Schwartz space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space) (the space of rapidly falling functions).

I understand that by defining distributions this way, they extend the functionals generated from Integration over a function in a nice way, while it is still possible to define operations like the Fourier-transform, multiplication with a function, or convolution in a nice and meaningful way.

What I don't understand however, is that physicists don't care what functions they apply the $\delta$-Distribution to. I have multiple times seen the $\delta$-Distribution be applied to polynomials or sinuses, which are clearly not elements of the Schwartz-space, as they are not falling. 
So my question is: How can one rigorously define the use of the $\delta$-Distribution, or of any other tempered Distribution in general, on a bigger class of functions, like polymials?

EDIT: I allready understand that physicists don't always care about rigorosity, yet I'd like to know wether there is a way to make the described procedure of applying tempered distributions to continuous functions rigorous.

Comment: $\delta$-distribution can be interpreted as a measure with compact support. As such, it is in the dual space to the space of all continuous functions, not just polynomials, and can be paired with them. Physicists have the right idea that mathematical concepts make sense beyond a particular formalism introduced for technical reasons (such as Schwarz's), although one has to settle on some such formalism to do things rigorously.

Comment: I think physicians will be physicists

Comment: I understand physicists will be physicists, yet most things they do can (with more effort) be defined in a rigorous way (or one Maybe has to emply another formalism, which I then would like to know about. 

Besides that, could the downvoter explain the downvote? Mabe I can adjust my Question?

Comment: Your question is too broad. One can write a long article about it, and still not all points will be covered. Maybe you should read Laurent Schwartz original work on distributions. It is only about 50 pages in French.

Comment: Note $\delta$ being a compactly supported distribution is why its Fourier transform can be defined directly as $F(\omega)=\langle \delta,e^{i \omega x}\rangle$. In the context of PDE, the Laplace transform the exponential growth and the analytic continuation problem is an invitation to consider analytic functionals instead of distributions on $S,C_c^\infty$, so that $(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\delta^{(n)}}{n!} i^n )\ast \phi(x) = \phi(x+i)$ for suitable $\phi$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $u$ is a distibution with compact support and that $\varphi \in C^\infty$ (not necessarily having compact support). Let $\rho \in C_c^\infty$ be such that $\rho \equiv 1$ on a neighborhood of the support of $u$. Then we can set
$$\langle u, \varphi \rangle := \langle u, \rho \varphi \rangle,$$
and this is independent of the choice of $\rho$.

Comment: Do I understand right that his "extension" of the Distribution $u$ can only be performed for distributions with compact support?

Comment: Yes, you have understood correctly. But for distributions with non-compact support there might be other ways to extend them if they behave good enough.

Answer (score 1):

As a measure, the Dirac $\delta$ measure can be applied to any function. Let some set $X$, then the powerset of $X$, symbolized by $\wp(X)$, is a $\sigma$-algebra and $$\delta_x(A):=\begin{cases}1,& x\in A\\0,&x\notin A\end{cases}\tag1$$ is a Dirac measure (for some chosen $x\in X$) on the measurable space $(X,\wp(X))$. That is, the triplet $(X,\wp(X),\delta_x)$ defines a measure space.

Now suppose that $\mathcal A$ is some $\sigma$-algebra in $E$ and $f\in E^X$. Then we says that $f$ is measurable when $f^{-1}(H)\in\wp(X)$ for every $H\in \mathcal A$, thus any function is measurable for this measure.

Then

$$\int_X f(y)\delta_x(y)=f(x)\tag2$$

for any chosen $f\in E^X$, so any function $f\in E^X$ is Bochner integrable respect to this measure, because $f=g$ almost everywhere where

$$g(t):=\begin{cases}f(t),& t=x\\0,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}\tag3$$

and $g$ is simple.

But then $(2)$ can be used to define a distribution on the space of test functions $\mathcal D(X)$, that is, $\delta_x:\mathcal D(X)\to E,\, \varphi\mapsto\varphi(x)$ as a distribution, then in this context $\delta_x$ is defined just in this space. This is the difference between the two ways to see the Dirac $\delta$.